# How to generate rounded square launcher icon android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-icons

I try to generate new launcher icon for my android project. I am taking png icon 512x512 and through Android Studio I am converting it New->Image Asset->(Launcher Icons Adaptive and legacy).  It generates icon, but the size of radius of rounded square is less than it was 7 month ago when I generated it for the first time. How can I make bigger radius for icon corners? Or it's new default icons for android? Thanks.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The shape of an adaptive icon is chosen by the launcher on Android 8.0+. You do not get a vote there.

Comment: Just go to project hierarchy, right click on **res** folder and choose **New > Image Asset**. Android team already include this tool into studio, for more details start from [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/image-asset-studio)

Comment: @Rade I made this, but it also generates transparent space around icon, please see description I added image.

Comment: @yozhik You can remove it by going to legacy tab, and changing **Shape** under **Legacy icon (API <= 25)** to none. By doing this you will lose rounding shape. I personally leave it as is, at the end it is Google's recommendation.

Comment: We support Android phones from 4.4 version, so I still need this.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Using this you can generate the rounded icon for the launcher.

https://jgilfelt.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html#foreground.space.trim=1&foreground.space.pad=0&foreColor=E8EAF6%2C0&crop=0&backgroundShape=square&backColor=3F51B5%2C100&effects=none&elevate=0

Comment: It also generates transparent space around icon, please see description I added image.

Comment: https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-generic.html#source.type=clipart&source.clipart=adb&source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0.05&size=32&padding=0&color=rgba(0%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200.54)&name=ic_adb

Comment: plz try with this, you can add padding according your requirement.

Comment: I have experimented with all padding sources, but still it has transparency

Comment: I experimented more and found out that for Legacy resources I must check not Square icon, but NONE - to avoid transparent background.

Answer (score 25):

**Generate Icon Via Android Studio**

Right click on app > Go to Image Assets > Choose icon type and other properties > Click next and finish.

[image]

Here you can generate all icon shapes and replace with new easily. If you choose icon type as adaptive and legacy it will generate both square shaped and round shaped. And replace with existing icons on finishing with the steps.

**Generate Via Online**

- [AndroidAssetStudio (romannurik)](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html#foreground.type=clipart&foreground.clipart=android&foreground.space.trim=1&foreground.space.pad=0.25&foreColor=rgba(96%2C%20125%2C%20139%2C%200)&backColor=rgb(68%2C%20138%2C%20255)&crop=0&backgroundShape=square&effects=none&name=ic_launcher)
- [AndroidAssetStudio (jgilfelt)](https://jgilfelt.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html#foreground.space.trim=1&foreground.space.pad=0&foreColor=E8EAF6%2C0&crop=0&backgroundShape=square&backColor=3F51B5%2C100&effects=none&elevate=0)
- [App Icon](https://appicon.co/)
- [Make App Icon](https://makeappicon.com/)

Comment: The first one is good. thanks for sharing

Answer (score 5):

You can use below links to generate rounded corner icons.

[makeappicon.com](https://makeappicon.com/)

[thomasfinch.me](http://thomasfinch.me/iosicon/)

[Android Asset Studio](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html#foreground.type=clipart&foreground.clipart=android&foreground.space.trim=1&foreground.space.pad=0.25&foreColor=rgba(96%2C%20125%2C%20139%2C%200)&backColor=rgb(68%2C%20138%2C%20255)&crop=0&backgroundShape=square&effects=none&name=ic_launcher)

Comment: Android Asset Studio is really awesome!

Answer (score 4):

you can try this tool...

[A collection of tools to easily generate assets such as launcher icons for your Android app.](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/)

Comment: It also generates transparent space around icon, please see description I added image.

Answer (score 1):

512x512 size is too big for launcher icon. Make it 108x108px and save it to svg by illustrator. Make sure your logo is inside 66x66px safe zone.

Comment: 512 is the original size, after generation it's: 48x48, 72x72, 96x96, 144x144, 192x192, but it has invisible borders

Comment: It also generates transparent space around icon, please see description I added image.

Comment: From my experience, 108 is okay. Try reading the link below, its a good article for adaptive icon.
https://www.google.com.ph/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://medium.com/google-design/designing-adaptive-icons-515af294c783&ved=2ahUKEwiGiouWw6jbAhUabisKHYXSAjkQjjgwCXoECAQQAQ&usg=AOvVaw2T2-9-HPeqId7vhZLYLUfm