# Xamarin: Android launch icon without padding

Tags: android, xamarin

I have created an app icon using Google's developer at guidelines https://developer.android.com/google-play/resources/icon-design-specifications. After setting the icon in MainActivity/AssemblyInfo/AndroidManifest, padding has been applied to it to make it round, instead of rounding the source image. The source icon is a full 512x512 pixel image as seen below.

[image: App icon source]

From this, I expected the result to look like this, with the rounding mask applied by Android.

[image: Expected result]

However, in reality, it looks like this.

[image: Actual result]

How do I allow my icon to fill the complete area of the circle?
(The results are being tested on Android 10.0, API level 29)

Answer (score 0):

In native Android, it provide the tool named Image Asset Studio of Android Studio to generate the following icon types: Launcher icons, Action bar and tab icons, Notification icons.
https://developer.android.com/studio/write/image-asset-studio#access

For xamarin, you could use `ANDROID ASSET STUDIO`. It is wasy to get the icon you want.

You could check the tool in the link below. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50565927/11850033

After generate the icon, set the icon in MainActivity.

```
  [Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/AppTheme", Icon = "@drawable/icon", MainLauncher = true )]
```

[image]

Comment: I used Android Asset Studio, following that link and still got padding